# How To Remove Wordpress Title From One Page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know this can be done with custom CSS, but I can't figure out the right way to do it.

I think I can figure it out for all of them if you show me how to do it with just the title.

For example, this is the element I want to remove: `<h1 class="page-title entry-title">`

I know that `{display: none}` is the CSS to hide an item, but how can I do it for only a specific page?

the website is: http://myinneryoga.com/strange-exotic-fruit-supplement/

Comment: Virtually impossible to answer this without a link to your site.  Depending on your theme, it's pretty tough to know the markup and classes being assigned to your titles.  It COULD be as simple as `#post-28 h1 {display: none;}`, but it really, really depends on your theme.

Comment: hi cale, this is the link to my site: http://myinneryoga.com/strange-exotic-fruit-supplement/ i want to remove the title on there called "STRANGE EXOTIC FRUIT SUPPLEMENT", can you tell me how you would take the steps to do this? literally driving me crazy for like 3 days tyring to figure this out

Comment: i also dnt want to remove all h1's because i use the h1 tag in other places in it.. i could just manually put the text size tho if it comes down to it

Comment: are you just setting the title like this ?                      <title>strange exotic fruit supplement</title>  , that is what it shows in HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `h1.page-title { display: none; }` to hide the title, this will affect ALL pages that use the same template.

If you want to do it specifically to this post use the following:

`#post-28 h1.page-title { display: none; }` the post number will lock it to that page only.

Comment: YES IT WORKED, thank u thank u thank u thank u thank u alskdjfaklsdjf thankkkksss.

Comment: Another way to make this change site wide and not rely on CSS and remove the markup completely, you can look into your template itself and remove `the_title()` but that's hopeful thinking without understanding your template structure...

Comment: this was driving me crazy. i had thoguht that #post-28 meant that the thing only linked to a "post" not a page. i had changed it myself to "page-28" trying to figure out why it wasnt working. so in order to call a PAGE or a POST, you still use #post-28 ?

Comment: part of your theme seems to use post-POSTID, and so by leveraging that you can target the specific post since this post's ID is #28. Glad it helped!

Comment: Here is some resource on Post vs Page: [Post vs Page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-vs-page/)

Comment: The solution of @fedmich could also work, but you need to check for the post id every time.

Comment: hey dexter, another question for you. i took off almost everything i needed to from the page, but the only two things left i want to remove is the "learn more" link from the header where my pic is and to also remove the link from the "my inner yoga" which brings the person to the front page. i dk how to grab the title tag with css or the learn more to pull it. i tried .site-title.a and added it to the display none, but didn't work. any ideas? im sure the title link can be removed, not sure if the "learn more" can be though =\

Comment: i want the title to still be displayed, but just the link to be removed

Comment: `.sidebar .textwidget a { display: none; }`

Comment: `.copyright a.site-link { display: none; }` CSS shouldn't be a solution to a template, you may want to modify your template (this could be in footer.php)

Answer (score 3):

Based on that page, the body has classes

```
 <body class="wordpress... singular-page singular-page-28 layout-1c"
```

28 is the page id of that page, so if you just want a CSS fix for this, you can use the code below

```
.singular-page-28 h1.page-title{
    display:none;
}
```

note, if you move the wordpress to another webhost, via export/import, you'll need to look at the page_id again if it changed

Comment: Note: there are several h1's in the body. All of them will get affected. Be specific like `h1.page-title`

Comment: Yes, dexter is right, we should put a specific .page-title there too. Thanks

Comment: yep, if you used the XML import/export feature the page-ids will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle, if this is the way you want it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qj4Us/

It simply looks for the targetted URL like "http://myinneryoga.com/strange-exotic-fruit-supplement/" and if found, hides the `h1` with `class=page-title`

Comment: thank you for the help. the other guy answered the quesetion, but i dont see anything setup on CSS or the result on this thing. i don't really get the PHP side so that's why i may be confused, but i have solved this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying CSS which will affect all pages we can make use of simple plugin. Below are the steps :

1. Click on Plugins > Add New.
2. Now search for Hide Title.
3. Install and activate the plugin.
4. Now click on Pages > All Pages.
5. Now edit the particular page where you want to hide the title.
6. Now, In the right panel you can see an option to Hide title. Check that and publish your changes.

[image]